# Setting scroll amount manually on react-virtualized table (multigrid)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

We are using react-virtualized table in our app. It is an multigrid. Suppose the table has 10000 rows and the table is currently scrolled to the 5000th row. What we want it, by clicking on a button the table should jump to the first row (scroll amount should be 0)

There are existing props such as **scrollToRow** or functions **scrollToPosition** or **scrollToCell** of the ***Grid***, but they help you scroll down, for example you are at the 1.row and using them you can set scroll amount to a specified value and jump to for example 100.row. But you can not go backwards, I mean scroll to first row when currently we are on the 200.

I found a temp. solution by calling:

```
scrollToTop = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.bodyGrid.bottomRightGrid.handleScrollEvent({scrollTop: 0});
    }, 100);
}
```

But it works only when called with setTimeout which does not seem fine.

I could not find any other way to change the scroll amount manually. My scenario is, user fetches 1000 rows and scrolls down to the 800.row. Then user clicks a button and it fetches some totally different new 100 rows for example, when the table is re-rendered (datasource is updated), it still keeps scrolling at the old position, even if whole datasource is replaced with a new one. I want that the scroll position goes to start, first row. But the table remembers the old scroll position at the 800 row, but currently we have only 100 rows so it scrolls a very out of bound location and points to a wrong position.